# Cannot connect to live server database using mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a live server database. Using Godaddy as host (NOT a very pleasant experience btw). I am getting this error: **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: YES) in /var/www/wp-content/themes/XXX_theme/inc/dbh.php on line 13**

My database connection:

```
<?php
$dbServername = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.db.XXXXXXXX.24d.hostedresource.net";
$dbUsername = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$dbPassword = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$dbName = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

I have tried:

- to use the exact credentials on the Godaddy page as suggested numerous times by support, and this is producing the error above.
- setting `$dbServername = "IP-adress"` (and "`IP-adress:portnumber`") and are getting: **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused**
- to inspect wp-config.php and noted that `define( 'DB_HOST', 'XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX' )` has another IP (but the same port) as the Godaddy IP. I have changed this to the Godaddy IP both with and without port number and are in both instances getting this: **Could not connect to database. This site is currently experiencing issues. Please try visiting at a later time. Error: 2002.**
- setting `$dbServername = "localhost"` and are getting: **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/wp-content/themes/XXX_theme/inc/dbh.php on line 14**.
- setting `$dbServername = "127.0.0.1"` and are getting: **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused**.
- to not pull my hair out! I hope that the problem/resolution "simply" is in my calibration somewhere. And that the hazzle of changing host can be avoided.

I'm greatful for any input! Thanks

Comment: Whatever you did that resulted in `Access denied for user 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: YES)` was the most correct try. But you have to figure out why the credentials are invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Hm it really seems correct. May it be related to the wordpress theme in some way?